# % of degradation in the response time from JMeter result

Tags: jmeter

I have the following report of performance test,

[image]

Want to calculate, how much % of degradation happened in `Phase 2` compared to `phase 1` and hence forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sounds like something from [primary school](https://www.cuemath.com/percent-difference-formula/)

The formula is:

```
(Phase 2 - Phase 1) / Phase 1 * 100
```

If you're using [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) or equivalent you can use the formula like:

```
=(C2-B2)/B2
```

and [format the resulting cell as "Percentage"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-percentages-de49167b-d603-4450-bcaa-31fba6c7b6b4)

You can also use JMeter online results analysis solution like [BlazeMeter Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) which has ability of comparison several JMeter test executions and it will calculate the percentages for you

Comment: @Dimitri BlazeMeter Sense is a good option. It has a file size limit for the free plan. Also, it's not possible to upgrade the plan. Getting message **Sense is deprecated, no plans are sold anymore.**